# How to insert into more than one MySQL tables use prepared statment

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

Tried to write two statment in one php file use prepared statment, i create two statment in one php file... here is my php file...

```
 <?php

require("config.inc.php");


if (!empty($_POST)) {


    if (empty($_POST['name'])|| empty($_POST['password'])) {


        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Please Enter Both a Username and Password.";

        die(json_encode($response));
    }


    $query        = " SELECT 1 FROM nama WHERE name= :name";
    $query_params = array(
        ':name' => $_POST['name']
    );
  $queryT        = " SELECT 1 FROM ProfilSiswa WHERE nama_lengkap= :nameT";
    $query_paramsT = array(
        ':nameT' => $_POST['nama_lengkap']
    );

    try {
        // These two statements run the query against your database table. 
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
        $stmtT   = $db->prepare($queryT);
        $resultT = $stmt->execute($query_paramsT);

    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {


        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error1. Please Try Again!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }



    $query = "INSERT INTO nama(name, info) VALUES ( :name, :info) ";
    $queryT = "INSERT INTO ProfilSiswa(nama_lengkap) VALUES ( :nameT) ";


$query_params = array(
        ':name' => $_POST['name'],
        ':info' => $_POST['info']
    );

$query_paramsT = array(
        ':nameT' => $_POST['nama_lengkap']
    );


    try {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);

        $stmtT   = $db->prepare($queryT);
        $resultT = $stmt->execute($query_paramsT);

    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {

        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error2. Please Try Again!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }


  ...
```

When I use that statement the values isn't insert to the tables and not showing an error when try to execute...

Comment: Consider using transactions btw because you are checking if a user exists and then later on you insert. This should be one whole transaction to prevent further failures later on!

Comment: I try to delete the line you mean, but still doesn't make a change...

Comment: There must be an error with MySQL. Add these 2 on top of the file  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see the error.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your code

```
$stmtT   = $db->prepare($queryT);
$resultT = $stmt->execute($query_paramsT);
```

Should be

```
$stmtT   = $db->prepare($queryT);
$resultT = $stmtT->execute($query_paramsT);
```